# C# - Convert an XML to a new XML with different structure

Tags: c#, xml, recursion, serialization, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that have nodes and child nodes, some type of a tree view. I would like to read these elements and extract the content to write them to a new XML with a new schema with lighter tree hirarchy.

In my code, I parse the XML file and read the nodes and child nodes but i can only print the nodes to console. I cant figure out how to write the nodes to the new XML in XML structure using the method's recursion.
i'm a noob to XML? am i missing something ?

XML EXAMPLE

```
<node clasification= some data about the node">
  <dimension = some sort of info layer>
  <children>
      <node clasification= some data about the node">
         <dimension = some sort of info layer>
         <children>
                  <node clasification= some data about the node">
                    <dimension = some sort of info layer>
                    </children>
                  </node>
                  <node clasification= some data about the node">
                    <dimension = some sort of info layer>
                    </children>
                  </node>
         </children>
      </node>
  </children>
</node>
```

my code is based on this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("../../Employees.xml");
    XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("*"); 
    ReadXML(root);
}

private static void ReadXML(XmlNode root)
{
    if (root is XmlElement)
    {
        DoWork(root);

        if (root.HasChildNodes)
            ReadXML(root.FirstChild);
        if (root.NextSibling != null)
            ReadXML(root.NextSibling);
    }
    else if (root is XmlText)
    {}
    else if (root is XmlComment)
    {}
}

private static void DoWork(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.Attributes["Code"] != null)
        if(node.Name == "project" && node.Attributes["Code"].Value == "Orlando")
            Console.WriteLine(node.ParentNode.ParentNode.Attributes["Name"].Value);
}
```

Please Help :)

Comment: I'm not sure parsing the xml in c# is the best course of action. I think I would go with [xslt transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/using-xslt-to-transform-an-xml-tree) instead. Here is a [link to an xslt tutorial.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/index.htm)

Comment: Why do you want to loose the structure?  I think you are taking the wrong approach.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Show us what xml you want to get as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to do it in a recursive way.
i cant share the final code because it is on a closed network with no access to the internet, but basically, i created a new node on the beginning of readxml , and returned it at the end, so i cant send the child object to it recursively...

something like that (pseudo code)

```
   private static XmlNode ReadXML(XmlNode root)
    {
      XmlNode tmp = new XmlNode;
        // pupulate the node attributes
        tmp = DoWork(root);

foreach (xmlnode childnode in node.childnodes)
{
     if (check if you want this node)
{
       XmlNodeList tmplist = childnode.childnodes;
            if (tmplist.HasChildNodes)
               {
                 tmp.newnode = new ChildNode[tmplist.count];
                 for (i=0;i<tmpnode.count;i++)
                   {
                     tmp.tmpnode[i] = ReadXML(tmplist.item(i));
                   }
                        }
        else 
        {}
    }
}
```

now its working fine